# Can I "reload" Apache2 configuration file without issues?

Tags: apache-http-server

Is

```
sudo /etc/init.d/apache2 reload
```

interrupting the operations on the webservers hosted by apache ?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Reload does a "Graceful Restart".

From the Apache documentation [Stopping and Restarting](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/stopping.html) :

> The USR1 or graceful signal causes the
>   parent process to advise the children
>   to exit after their current request
>   (or to exit immediately if they're not
>   serving anything). The parent re-reads
>   its configuration files and re-opens
>   its log files. As each child dies off
>   the parent replaces it with a child
>   from the new generation of the
>   configuration, which begins serving
>   new requests immediately.

In theory no operations will be interrupted, but there will be a wave of server-processes restarting, with some (normally trivial enough) overhead.

In effect there are more variables involved, such as whether you are using prefork or worker, the number of children that you have specified, and in the case of worker the max threads per child.

Comment: ok. So, more precisely, if my customer is performing an order on a php based e-shop. If i reload apache without restarting, is he going to have issues ? thanks

Comment: Again *in theory*, as long as the customer order is handled in one php call, and as long as the reload is not critical for the correct functioning of "old generation" servers, then all will pass gracefully and well. But it's easy enough to test in practice.

Comment: Note that the init scripts are added by the packager. The ones for redhat/oracle linux apache v2.2 send a -HUP signal when calling _service httpd reload_. For a graceful restart _service httpd graceful_ should be called which calls _/usr/sbin/apachectl graceful_.